# Preg match all characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

how to preg match all characters letters, numbers, special characters f.e:  ²,▲,ƒ ² ‰ © £ ± ß ° 1/2 ¿ « » ™...etc...???

and others special characters???

Answer (score 4):

The regex syntax for any character except line breaks (\r or \n) is `.`, thus if you wanted to match one or more of any character, your regex would simply be `.+` [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html). However, some regex flavours do permit you to specify a flag which will allow the `.` to include line break characters.

As noted by Damien, what is the point of using preg_match?

Answer (score 2):

In RegEx, the dot sign (.) will match any character, so

```
preg_match('/hel.o/', $str);
```

Will match `hello`, `helpo`, `hel o`, `hel%o` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Dot (`.`) stands for any character.

Comment: something like this: preg_match_all('[start(.)end]', $var1, $var2); It's not working, dot(.) is bad idea

Comment: @MarcinKostrzewa if you preg_match anything, why don't just accept the string right away as it is?

Answer (score 1):

`[\w\W]` or `[\s\S]` matches all characters, including line breaks.

But these expressions are much slower then `.`, so be careful when working with big strings.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to append /u in the pattern to tell preg_match to use utf8 strings, check manual for /u option and just paste the simple in the php code.

just remember to save the .php in utf8 mode or do some decodes manually.